# Change XML with xmlstarlet depending on another element

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

i will cry.... i read 2 posts it wont work for me.... i tested for half a day.... my xml looks like this:

```
<ConfigData xmlns="http://xml.avaya.com/endpointAPI">
<version>1</version>
<parameter>
<name>EnablePresence</name>
<value>1</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>CurrentSkin</name>
<value>1</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>DialPlanNationalPhoneNumbLengthList</name>
<value>6</value>
</parameter>
</ConfigData>
```

xmlstarlet should change the value to (replacing the old file...)

```
<ConfigData xmlns="http://xml.avaya.com/endpointAPI">
<version>1</version>
<parameter>
<name>EnablePresence</name>
<value>1</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>CurrentSkin</name>
<value>1</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>DialPlanNationalPhoneNumbLengthList</name>
<value>7</value>
</parameter>
</ConfigData>
```

my last try was:

```
xml edit --inplace --update '//parameter[name="DialPlanNationalPhoneNumbLengthList"]/value' -v 7 config.xml
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer and accept (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.... xml edit -L -N x="xml.avaya.com/endpointAPI"; -u "/x:ConfigData/x:parameter[x:name='DialPlanNationalPhoneNumbLengthList']/x:value‌​" -v 7 config.xml Next step is to edit multiple values...... ideas?

Another problem: is it possible to solve the namespace problem with on placeholder for all namespaces?